# Azure B2C Group-based access control does not show userMessage

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I've been working on implementing group-based access control for a B2C Tenant.
I've setup an API hook (POST) which accepts the user's ObjectId, validates if the user is in the permitted groups through Graph API and returns:

- 200 OK when successful
- 409 Conflict when not succesful

Below is the object returned with a 409:

```
{
"version": "1.0.0",
"status": 409,
"userMessage": "User is not authorized for this application"
}
```

For some reason, this message is not shown to the user, but rather a redirect occurs to
{{B2cUrl}}/#error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C%3a+User+is+not+authorized+for+this+application%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+...8%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+...%3a03%3a39Z%0d%0a&state=...

In my user Journey, i have included the following orchestra

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
   <ClaimsExchanges>
      <ClaimsExchange Id="RESTValidateProfile" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-ValidateProfile" />
   </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

How can i get the user error message shown in the Login page for the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your rest api technical profile from a validation technical profile. The validation technical profile should be configured against the self asserted technical profile (login page) such that it can then return an error to it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-claims-validation#validate-the-user-input

In its current form, the REST API is called after the page is submitted and a redirect starts. Therefore any error is just sent back to the app, as there is no page rendered at that time.

Comment: The current flow is a Technical Profile in a TrustFrameworkBase, with a ValidationTechnicalProfile in an extension depending on the application. This means i cannot place a Validation Technical Profile in the profile already in the extension. How could i resolve this issue?

Comment: Why can’t you? Not following your description. Maybe use the names of the technical profiles so I can understand with context.

Comment: Sorry, i'll step through:
In TrustFrameworkBase, there's SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email
In every TrustFrameworkExtension (Application dependant, there are 6), there is login-NonInteractive, which is used as a Validation Technical Profile.
My group-based validation is application-dependant, so needs to be placed in TrustFrameworkExtensions, but since login-Noninteractive is already in use as a validation profile, i cannot use the group validation REST-ValidateProfile as validation profile in  login-Noninteractive

Comment: You wouldn’t call it in login-noninteractive, you’d call it as a validation technical profile in SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email. But you’d define it and call in the extension file that is app dependant if the logic of the REST call is also app dependent. You can add an override for SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email in each app dependant file.

Comment: Thanks for the further explaination. I've got it working now.